# Linear Momentum Based Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, momentum, collision

> A ball moving along a straight line collides elastically with another stationary ball of the same mass. At the moment of collision the angle between the straight line passing through the centres of the balls and the direction of initial motion of striking ball is $\theta$. Find the fraction of kinetic energy converted into potential energy at the moment of maximum deformation. Consider the $x$ axis to be a rigid plane like a floor. There is rolling motion.
>   [image: I tried to draw a rough picture]

Please help me as to along which line I should apply linear momentum conservation. I have tried along common diameter but its not working. Any hint will do.

Comment: pick some perpendicular axes and apply momentum conservation along *both* of them

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)

Answer (score 2):

This is the right way to represent the collision: [image]

Since the masses are equal the resulting vectors will form a right angle and linear momenta on the y-axis are equal and the sum of momenta on the x-axis is equal to the original momentum of the cueball $mv'+m_ov' = mv$

Comment: Noooooo!!!please try to understand the problem i mean..i meant the one ball hits another ball in rest while spinning and its current velocity is at an angle to common diameter...your representation is implying something else!!!!

Comment: The x-axis is something like floor.

Comment: @Sanchayan Dutta :you didn't tell about spinning in the question.